# Autofill feature with Listbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have a Listbox with items being 'first name' loaded from a table of a database,

1. now i want an autofill feature where if a user types like 'a' all the names starting with 'a' first name should be show in the listbox
2. and after some button click the original data should be repopulated in the listbox

for 2nd one i.e.. repopulating hope i can do with below code

```
protected void btnRePopulate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet oDs = ReadDataSet();
    Listbox1.DataTextField = "Name";
    Listbox1.DataValueField = "ID";
    Listbox1.DataSource = oDs;
    Listbox1.DataBind();
}
```

but for the 1st i have some things on which iam working (i am using textbox keyup event to fire when the user types 'a' or whatever)

1. clear the listbox and add the names which starts with 'a', but not sure is it possible from client side
2. or set another listbox visible with names filtered from the original and hide the original listbox, for which i am not able to set visible property either from js or codebehind
3. no i dont want to use ajax autofill

is there a better option apart from the above two...

Comment: you may require at east three characters to be typed in order get the List of items from your database that match the "starts with" expression.

Comment: thanks for ur reply... yes u are absolutely right, even i thought of it, but as i already have the records i.e.. in the list box do i need to make another round trip to the database for a filter of the record which i already have...

Comment: or is there a way to access the dataset from the java script, which fetches entirely, using which i can filter the data from java script..any idea guys....

Answer (score 0):

This filtering and resetting is best done on the client side itself. That way you don't make unnecessary server calls. Here is a extension method in jQuery.

```
$(function() {
  $('#select').filterByText($('#textbox'), true);
});
```

Extension method:

```
jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox, selectSingleMatch) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var select = this;
    var options = [];
    $(select).find('option').each(function() {
      options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
    });
    $(select).data('options', options);
    $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
      var options = $(select).empty().scrollTop(0).data('options');
      var search = $.trim($(this).val());
      var regex = new RegExp(search,'gi');

      $.each(options, function(i) {
        var option = options[i];
        if(option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
          $(select).append(
             $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
          );
        }
      });
      if (selectSingleMatch === true && 
          $(select).children().length === 1) {
        $(select).children().get(0).selected = true;
      }
    });
  });
};
```

I found this on Lessan Vaezi's blog with a [live demo](http://www.lessanvaezi.com/filter-select-list-options/) on how to do it.